# How this JS code is working and what form it is encoded in?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scraper

I have been developing Data Scraping scripts for past 3 years but never had tough time like this.

I am scraping a [site](http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=XJO), To prevent scraping, it shows message `Please enable JS in your browser`

But then there is JS code that creates some sort of cookie or token, and redirects to the actual page.

https://pastebin.com/BL95Z48C

I only want to know what form that code is encoded? How can I decode it?

Answer (score 1):

The code has been obfuscated using some kind of JavaScript Obfuscator.

Here is the de-obfuscated `/` decoded version of that code ... [p­astebi­­n­.com/­Rjcge­Tfs](https://pastebin.com/RjcgeTfs)
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: @GottZ Yes it is human readable :) Which part you couldn't read ?

Comment: @GottZ please also post how to decode it ... thanks for time

Comment: lets just say there is lots of stuff in there that i'm currently reversing. like $(123,123,123,123,123) etc.

Comment: @GottZ I dont know what you said, :( I am waiting for your answer

Comment: @GottZ and how do you interpret those values?

Comment: @ℊααnd you'll see ;) they'll all be reversed back to to human readable state. i'm almost done already

Comment: My goal is to scrape the page http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=XJO ... If you clear all cookies, and then reload page, if sends a POST request with some variables and then shows actual page, I want to know how those variables are generated that are being sent to POST ... https://pastebin.com/uRvBsWZN is actually the POST code ... but it stops working after a minute,

Comment: just a glympse at what i've already managed to deobfuscate. just compare it and you'll see the progress: https://pastebin.com/Vf9CJJMn

Comment: @GottZ Thanks for effort so far ... I would like to know how they are sending the POST request ... https://pastebin.com/cGH5pKQ6 is the RAW HTML which they show on page load, but after that, some POST request is sent from the code

Answer (score 1):

so. what did i do so far?

i took your code, threw it in [jsnice.org](http://jsnice.org) and [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org)

i noticed two code blocks wrapped in eval functions. i simply took them out of the evals and copied the code blocks into jsnice again.

from there i did this:

```
code.replace(/\/\*.+\*\//g, '')
.replace(/(?:\$|to8bitStream)\(([\d, ]+)\)/g, (a,b) => JSON.stringify(b.split(', ').map(x=>String.fromCharCode(x-63)).join``))
.replace(/(?:key|get)\((\d+)\)/g, (a,b) => JSON.stringify(parseInt(b,10).toString(36)))
.replace(/get\(0x([\da-f]+)\)/gi, (a,b) => JSON.stringify(parseInt(b,16).toString(36)))
.replace(/(?:forEach|createDom)\((\d+)\)/g, (a,b)=>746>parseInt(b))
.replace(/(?!=\s*)\["([a-z\d_]+)"\]/gi, (a,b)=>'.'+b);
```

to get a modified version of that code that i then threw just back into jsnice to get the following output:

https://gist.github.com/GottZ/ce2f7dea949b2b7af64606426e56adde

i'll now be afk for some minutes and will continue deobfuscating that `securemsg` stuff.

PS: keep in mind i'm doing this for free.